# python ModuleNotFoundError error in absolute import package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have a file structure like this.

```
.
└── E:\test
    ├
    ├── M2
    │   └── demo.py
    |       
    │       
    └── MA
    │    └── MA1
    │    │   ├── __init__.py
    │    │   │
    │    │   └── ma1.py
    │    ​│__ __init__.py
```

**ma1.py**

```py
def foo():
    print("I am here")
```

**demo.py**

```py
from MA.MA1.ma1 import foo
print(foo())
```

I am use python3.8 and win10 system.
In cmd I try to `cd test` directory and `python .\M2\demo.py`, it show error?

```
PS E:\test> python .\M2\demo.py    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\M2\demo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from MA.MA1.ma1 import foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MA'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember 2 things:

1- Python searches `sys.path` to find modules and packages.

2- When you run your script like you did, **only** it's directory will be added to the `sys.path`. So you have to add the directory which `MA` is inside it manually. Do the following inside `demo.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r'E:\test')

from MA.MA1.ma1 import foo
print(foo())
```

Alternatively you can set `PYTHONPATH` variable.

Answer (score 3):

The python interpreter does not search modules in `test\` directory since you execute the script from `test\M2\`. You can tell python to search from `test\` by adding directory "test" to the `PYTHONPATH` variable.
For windows command line:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;E:\test
```

For linux terminal:

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=path_to_test_dir
```

Comment: Sorry, I like the previous answer.