# What is the format for importing python variables and functions from another file in another directory

Tags: python, import

Currently developing a bot in discord.py, I have these imports which grab different functions and or variables from different py files:

```
from core.db.read import return_all_document_id
from core.extras.terminal import database_Critical
from core.db.write import New_Member
from core.main import *
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
```

I was told that using for example, core.db.read was the right way to do it, I'm getting this traceback though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mj\Documents\Pycharm\wake\core\extensions\events.py", line 1, in <module>
    from core.db.read import return_all_document_id
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'"
```

Is there a better way to do this? If not what could be my issue here?

[My folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMAwD.png)

Comment: It depends on how you are running this.  If you are running `events.py` by itself, then clearly it doesn't know how to find the `core` module.

Comment: I think I answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68375393/13944524

Answer (score 0):

Try using this , to import a module from another folder we can try placing an empty file named  '**init**.py' (use double underscore on both sides of init) into that folder and use the relative path with the dot notation
because it signals to Python that the folder should be treated as package