# How do I import a class from another folder?

Tags: python, import, parent, importerror

I am trying to import checkaxis.py from utils to datasetinfo.py in the dataset folder. This is how the structure looks like:

```
MSseg
|- __init__.py
|-- utils
|       |- __init__.py
|.      | - checkaxis.py
|-- dataset
          |- __init__.py
          |- datasetinfo.py
```

The **init**.py method is empty. The way I am trying to import is:

```
from .MSseg.utils.checkaxis import CheckAxis
```

I get the following import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datasetinfo.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .MSseg.utils.checkaxis import CheckAxis
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: try this `from .utils.checkaxis import CheckAxis`. For your info if you have __init__.py it's a package not a separate folder

Comment: Getting this:
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "datasetinfo.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.checkaxis import CheckAxis
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package<

since you didn't mention anything about how the init should look, I made it empty.

Comment: what directory are you running the main Python process from?

Comment: well I at the moment I am just running at dataset folder to test the program, but it will run at MSseg with config.py eventually.

Comment: If you're in the directory called `MSseg`, you just want `from utils.checkaxis import CheckAxis`; if you're running from the directory called `dataset`, see if you can run from its parent directory instead

Comment: So atm I want to run it from the folder dataset, but I don't how to, since I am getting these errors.

Comment: just put another script in the parent to import what you need and run it there, otherwise you'll need `sys.path` hacks to go to the parent directory as [**Canbach** sort-of suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68534354/4541045)

Comment: I still have to import the class check_axis in order to make it run, or I think I misunderstood your answer

Comment: consider writing a small script in the parent directory which can do something like `from dataset.datasetinfo import main`, then everything will be relative to the root of the code repository

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68375393/13944524

Answer (score 0):

In your MSseg.utils.checkaxis init.py add

```
from .checkaxis import CheckAxis
```

Then in MSseg.dataset.datasetinfo.py

```
from MSseg.utils import CheckAxis
```

Comment: I am getting the following:   
File "datasetinfo.py", line 11, in <module>
from utils import CheckAxis
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datasetinfo.py", line 11, in <module>
    from MSseg.utils import CheckAxis
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MSseg'

Comment: What do you mean by the "from MSseg.utils import CheckAxis"
I feel like this will tell python that there is another MSseg package inside MSseg package.
So, doing this will make sense "from .MSseg.utils import CheckAxis"

Answer (score 0):

Since both utils and and dataset are from the same director
try this out:

```
> from utils.checkaxis import CheckAxis
```

Python should recoginize the package.
Just let me know if it still gives an error. We can find another solution.

Comment: File "datasetinfo.py", line 13, in <module>
    from utils.checkaxis import CheckAxis
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

Answer (score -2):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('folder location')
import your module
```

Comment: Which "folder location"? Where to put this code? Which module to import?

Comment: the path where your folder is, something like /home/username/program

Comment: The OP has given a specific folder structure. Please answer to those parameters.

Comment: I actually tried this, but it wouldn't go through. I wrote sys.path.append("./MSseg/utils) and from utils import checkaxis,but getting error.